# Why IntegerAttribute doesn't resolve the ErrorMessageResourceType?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, attributes, data-annotations

I'm doing asp.net MVC3 project , In my class model (CarModel) , I putted an Integer attribute to validate property ModelYear, I tried to customize my error message based on localization , my code:

```
[Integer(ErrorMessageResourceName = "OnlyNumberValidator", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AddNewCar))]
public Nullable<int> ModelYear { get; set; }
```

but it didn't take my error message and just shown the default message "The field ModelYear must be a number"

Note: it works on Required attribute !

Answer (score 0):

Please check your references and make sure you're using the `DataAnnotationsExtensions.Mvc` in addition to `DataAnnotationsExtensions` in the Nuget packages. Without the Mvc specific library it will result in the same output as you're currently experiencing.

Comment: Yes I'm using DataAnnotationsExtensions.Mvc